# Is there a way to disable and enable the standard gateway in WIndows with cmd

Tags: networking, cmd, lan, gateway

I try to disable and enable the standart gateway so that you cant use the internet but be still in the local Network.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to do a disconnecting the Internet by this way. But it is possible:

1. Open the CMD window as an administrator.
2. View the status before editing: `route print | findstr "0.0.0.0"`
3. Delete the default route: `route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0`
4. Re-view the status after editing: `route print | findstr "0.0.0.0"`

The change is valid only until the PC is restarted or the dynamically assigned IP address (DHCP) is restored. Auto-renewal of the address takes place in the middle of the lease time period, it can be 30 minutes, 12 hours, etc. This is one of the reasons why this method of solution is not reliable at all.

It is better to block the PC's access to the Internet on your Internet router.